# select groups having same value in a column

Tags: sql, hana

| Group_No | Id | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | Active |
| 1 | 102 | Active |
| 2 | 201 | Active |
| 2 | 202 | Approved |
| 2 | 203 | Active |
| 3 | 301 | Inactive |
| 3 | 302 | Active |
| 4 | 401 | Denied |
| 4 | 402 | Denied |

I have to select the groups which all Ids have either 'Active' OR 'Approved' value in Status column. I tried below query.

```
select group_no
from <table>
where status in ('Active','Approved') 
group by group_no 
having(count(distinct status)) = 1;
```

The desired output should be groups 1 and 2. But I am facing problem since 'Active' and 'Approved' are distinct but they are to be considered as same for my purpose. Please suggest how to achieve desired output.

Comment: Please explain more precise your intention. If you want to only accept "Active" and "Approved", why not write something like SELECT ...FROM...WHERE status IN ('Active','Approved') AND group_no NOT IN (SELECT group_no FROM...WHERE status IN ('Inactive','Denied')) ?

Comment: Remove the WHERE clause, and use HAVING clause to make sure there are no other status values.

Comment: @JonasMetzler There are several other statuses apart from 'Inactive' or 'Denied', so its difficult to put then all inside "IN" in the subquery.

Comment: Ok, you can of course also write ...NOT IN ('Active','Approved') instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid sub-selects and want to be flexible in terms of new status to be introduced, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT group_no
FROM <table>
GROUP BY group_no
HAVING 1 = MIN(CASE WHEN status IN ('Active', 'Approved') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```